# Date field in where clause - if date in field is >= 67

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to pull up records based on a datetime field. In the where clause I want the query to look at the date in the datetime field and if its greater than or equal to 67 days, I want the records to show up. How do I do this?

I have used the sysdate in the where clause before.

Comment: Which database and version are you on? Where is the code you attempted to run?

Comment: Care to share your code? Hard to tell you what is wrong if we don't know what your query looks like....

Comment: Which dbms?????  `SQL` is just a language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Date functions vary for different vendors.  So tag your question properly!.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Thank you to those who were going to help.

Answer: `trunc(sysdate-s.affecteddate) > 67`

I am using MS Access via pass through query.

Comment: @cjschwartz Pass-through queries use the sql syntax of the target dbms rather than MS Access' own. In this case that's (probably?) Oracle. Not an issue, but will help the right people see your future questions if tags are correct.

Comment: @cjschwartz  @OwlsSleeping might be correct as I were not able to find any reference to `trunc` in access. Orace, mysql or anything else behind it. Please let us know.